# How to multiply 2 table/list in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySql I obtained 2 list/tables from these 2 queries. Table 1 contains Quantities for a type of ticket, Table 2 contains Prices of a type of ticket.

Table 1:

```
SELECT Count(`ticket`.`Ticket_type`) AS Counter
FROM `ticket`
WHERE ((`ticket`.`Ticket_type` = 'Adult') OR (`ticket`.`Ticket_type` = 'Senior'))
GROUP BY `ticket`.`Ticket_type`
```

Table2 :

```
SELECT  `ticketprice`.`price`
FROM `ticketprice`
WHERE ((`ticketprice`.`Ticket_type` = 'Adult') OR (`ticketprice`.`Ticket_type` = 'Senior'))
```

My question is how do I being to multiply these two tables? `(Qunatity * Price) = Total`

Will Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables and multiply:

```
SELECT t.ticket_type, COUNT(*) AS quantity, p.price, p.price * COUNT(*) AS total
FROM ticket AS t
JOIN ticketprice AS p ON t.ticket_type = p.ticket_type
WHERE t.ticket_type IN ('Adult', 'Senior')
GROUP BY t.ticket_type
```